# Is there any reagent that can help me obtain the protein in a 14 μm tissue without damaging the morphology of the tissue

Tags: proteins, experimental-design, tissue

I need to extract proteins, but I want to protect the morphology of the tissue. Can I use lysis buffer directly？

Comment: The morphology of tissue is due in large part to proteins. Trying to extract them with lysis buffer will destroy the tissue.